# Determining File System of volume

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, filesystem, disk-volume

I would like to know the FileSystem is used by Hard Disk/Volume

Here one List with some FileSystems:

- HFS+
- APFS
- NTFS
- exFAT
- extFS
- Ext4

Here the pictures...

[image]

[image]

For me that information is not clear.

According to Pictures **What File System (from the List) I need to assume?**

**EDIT:**

```
sh-3.2# diskutil list /dev/disk7
/dev/disk7 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk7
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk7s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HD710A                  999.9 GB   disk7s2
sh-3.2#
```

Other command

```
sh-3.2# diskutil info /dev/disk7
   Device Identifier:         disk7
   Device Node:               /dev/disk7
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk7
   Device / Media Name:       HD710A

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported

   Disk Size:                 1.0 TB (1000204886016 Bytes) (exactly 1953525168 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Info not available
   Virtual:                   No

sh-3.2#
```

**OTHER EDIT:**

```
sh-3.2# diskutil listFilesystems
Formattable file systems

These file system personalities can be used for erasing and partitioning.
When specifying a personality as a parameter to a verb, case is not considered.
Certain common aliases (also case-insensitive) are listed below as well.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PERSONALITY                     USER VISIBLE NAME                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case-sensitive APFS             APFS (Case-sensitive)                           
  (or) APFSX
APFS                            APFS                                            
  (or) APFSI
ExFAT                           ExFAT                                           
Free Space                      Free Space                                      
  (or) FREE
MS-DOS                          MS-DOS (FAT)                                    
MS-DOS FAT12                    MS-DOS (FAT12)                                  
MS-DOS FAT16                    MS-DOS (FAT16)                                  
MS-DOS FAT32                    MS-DOS (FAT32)                                  
  (or) FAT32
HFS+                            Mac OS Extended                                 
Case-sensitive HFS+             Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive)                
  (or) HFSX
Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+   Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)     
  (or) JHFSX
Journaled HFS+                  Mac OS Extended (Journaled)                     
  (or) JHFS+
UFSD_NTFS                       Microsoft NTFS                                  
UFSD_EXTFS                      extFS 2                                         
UFSD_EXTFS3                     extFS 3                                         
UFSD_EXTFS4                     extFS 4                                         
sh-3.2#
```

diskutil info disk7s2

```
sh-3.2# diskutil info disk7s2
   Device Identifier:         disk7s2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk7s2
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk7

   Volume Name:               HD710A
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /Volumes/HD710A

   Partition Type:            Apple_HFS
   File System Personality:   Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):             hfs
   Name (User Visible):       Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                   Journal size 81920 KB at offset 0x1d1c000
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       Yes
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               E70BFAA0-6059-3E92-91D1-0C9B603E682D
   Disk / Partition UUID:     9864BEC6-897D-4D4F-A8DA-60A7594D5222
   Partition Offset:          209735680 Bytes (409640 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 999.9 GB (999860912128 Bytes) (exactly 1952853344 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        999.9 GB (999860912128 Bytes) (exactly 1952853344 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:         752.1 GB (752090554368 Bytes) (exactly 1468926864 512-Byte-Units) (75.2%)
   Volume Free Space:         247.8 GB (247770357760 Bytes) (exactly 483926480 512-Byte-Units) (24.8%)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          No

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Info not available

sh-3.2#
```

Comment: The right command is : ```diskutil info disk7s2```

Comment: In the screen shot of Disk Utility, it clearly shows it's formatted Mac OS Extended (Journaled). What do you not understand?

Answer (score 3):

In the upper image, a drive is highlighted. This drive is using a "GUID Partition Map". In the lower image, a partition on the drive is highlighted. I see the file system is "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)". The label is "HD710A".

User [Gordon Davisson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/427/gordon-davisson) has suggested the following (in a comment):

> One source of confusion: "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" is the user-friendly name for Journaled HFS+ (sometimes abbreviated JHFS+). You can get a list of name equivalences with `diskutil listFilesystems`.

Below is the output from `diskutil listFilesystems` when entered in a Big Sur (macOS 11.2) Terminal application window.

```
Formattable file systems

These file system personalities can be used for erasing and partitioning.
When specifying a personality as a parameter to a verb, case is not considered.
Certain common aliases (also case-insensitive) are listed below as well.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PERSONALITY                     USER VISIBLE NAME                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case-sensitive APFS             APFS (Case-sensitive)                           
  (or) APFSX
APFS                            APFS                                            
  (or) APFSI
ExFAT                           ExFAT                                           
Free Space                      Free Space                                      
  (or) FREE
MS-DOS                          MS-DOS (FAT)                                    
MS-DOS FAT12                    MS-DOS (FAT12)                                  
MS-DOS FAT16                    MS-DOS (FAT16)                                  
MS-DOS FAT32                    MS-DOS (FAT32)                                  
  (or) FAT32
HFS+                            Mac OS Extended                                 
Case-sensitive HFS+             Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive)                
  (or) HFSX
Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+   Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)     
  (or) JHFSX
Journaled HFS+                  Mac OS Extended (Journaled)                     
  (or) JHFS+
```

The Disk Utility application does not always display all partitions and/or volumes. The drive in your example probably has an "FAT32" formatted EFI partition and may have a "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" formatted macOS Recovery partition.

To get a better idea of all partitions and volumes, you should enter the command `diskutil list` in a Terminal application window. Additional information can be obtained by using the `diskutil info device` command, where `device` can be an identifier or label.

> Note: After using the Disk Utility application to perform a drive operation, you may need to quit (or Force Quit) and open the Disk Utility to see the correct results.

Also, the Disk Utility and `diskutil` commands show cached information about unmounted volumes. For example, if you were to use the `newfs_msdos` command to format and change the label of an unmounted EFI volume, the Disk Utility and diskutil command would not show the change until after the EFI partition was mounted or macOS was restarted.

### Update:

After reading the addition input provided when the OP edited the question, I can add the information being sought can be output by entering the following commands. Here, `device` should to be replaced by either an identifier or label.

```
diskutil info -plist device | grep -A1 -e FilesystemName -e Content
```

These commands can be placed in a function, as shown below.

```
fs() { diskutil info -plist $1|grep -A1 -e FilesystemName -e Content; }
```

> The `Content` is the name assigned by macOS to the partition type stored in the drive partition table. The `FilesystemName` is the name assign by macOS to volume format.

Here is an example from a 2011 iMac with a Windows 10, High Sierra, Ubuntu triple boot setup. Below is the output from `diskutil list`.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data Coelacanth              100.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data COELACANTH2             48.9 GB    disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Marlin                  250.0 GB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5
   6:                  Apple_HFS Linux HFS+ ESP          209.7 MB   disk0s6
   7:           Linux Filesystem                         82.7 GB    disk0s7
   8:                 Linux Swap                         16.4 GB    disk0s8
   9:                  Apple_HFS UBUNTU                  939.5 MB   disk0s9
  10:       Microsoft Basic Data REFIND                  134.2 MB   disk0s10
```

The commands below will provide the desired information for all the partitions.

```
for i in  {1..10};do echo disk0s$i;fs disk0s$i;done
```

The output is given below. The no `FilesystemName` match was found identifier `disk0s7` because normally macOS can not mount `ext4` formatted Linux partitions.

```
disk0s1
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>EFI</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>MS-DOS FAT32</string>
disk0s2
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Microsoft Basic Data</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>NTFS</string>
disk0s3
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Microsoft Basic Data</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>ExFAT</string>
disk0s4
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Apple_HFS</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>Journaled HFS+</string>
disk0s5
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Apple_Boot</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>Journaled HFS+</string>
disk0s6
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Apple_HFS</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>HFS+</string>
disk0s7
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Linux Filesystem</string>
disk0s8
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Linux Swap</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>Linux Swap</string>
disk0s9
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Apple_HFS</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>Journaled HFS+</string>
disk0s10
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Microsoft Basic Data</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>MS-DOS FAT16</string>
```

Here is another example from a VirtualBox virtual machine with a Big Sur and Windows 10 dual boot setup. Below is the output from `diskutil list`.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *274.9 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         224.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨BOOTCAMP⁩                50.4 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +224.3 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨BigSurNVMe - Data⁩       2.3 GB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 292.5 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                613.6 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨BigSurNVMe⁩              15.1 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.1 GB    disk1s5s1
   7:                APFS Volume ⁨MyStuff⁩                 802.8 KB   disk1s7
```

The commands below will provide the desired information for all the physical partitions.

```
for i in {1..3}; do echo disk0s$i;fs disk0s$i;done
```

The output is given below. The no `FilesystemName` match was found identifier `disk0s2` because this partition has an APFS container.

```
disk0s1
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>EFI</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>MS-DOS FAT32</string>
disk0s2
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Apple_APFS</string>
disk0s3
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>Microsoft Basic Data</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>NTFS</string>
```

The command below will provide the desired information for all the APFS volumes.

```
for i in {1..5} 5s1 7; do echo disk1s$i;fs disk1s$i;done
```

The output is given below. These volumes reside in an APFS container and therefore do have a partition type stored in a drive partition table. Internally, macOS uses the UUID of `41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` for the `Context`. Eventually, macOS has not assigned a name to this UUID.

```
disk1s1
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>APFS</string>
disk1s2
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>APFS</string>
disk1s3
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>APFS</string>
disk1s4
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>APFS</string>
disk1s5
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>APFS</string>
disk1s5s1
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>APFS</string>
disk1s7
    <key>Content</key>
    <string>41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC</string>
--
    <key>FilesystemName</key>
    <string>Case-sensitive APFS</string>
```

Comment: One source of confusion: "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" is the user-friendly name for Journaled HFS+ (sometimes abbreviated JHFS+). You can get a list of name equivalences with `diskutil listFilesystems`.